# Burnikel Ziegler division

Tags: arithmetic, divisibility

I am implementing [fast recursive division by Burnikel and Ziegler](http://bioinfo.ict.ac.cn/~dbu/AlgorithmCourses/Lectures/Hasselstrom2003.pdf). I'm unable get **Algorithm 3.4 Divide-and-conquer division (3 by 2)** on page 14.

if $A_2 > B_1$ then remainder may exceed $\beta^{2n}$.

As $R_1 = (A_2 − B_1)\beta^n + A_1 + B_1$

And $R ← R_1\beta^n + A4 − QB_0$

($B_0$ can be $0$)

How the remainder is exceeding $\beta^{2n}$ when $B < \beta^{2n}$?

e.g. $A = (11 01 10)_2$ and $B = (1000)_2$ R will be $(11110)_2$